# filtering search results of shopping website

Tags: php, mysql, filter

what is the way of designing an optimized schema's for a shopping website that can provide different filter options for different categories.

In [TV Category](http://www.flipkart.com/tv-video/tv-20014) the filters available are `Type`, `Display Features`, `Display Size`. Whereas in computer accessories like [keyboard](http://www.flipkart.com/search-computer-accessories?query=keyboard&from=all&searchGroup=computers) the filters available are `Type` and `Interface`. and the filters change for various products.

Filtering the result by cost and brand can be done easily as they have separate column in the table.

but how to design a table of items which have different types of multiple filters which varies by category. My guess would be having a column named `filter` for every item. that holds these data's. But is it the best way of using filters as the column `filter` have multiple filters.

Comment: TIP: set `index` for every filered item.

Answer (score 0):

Having one column surely is not the best way if you have a lot of data.
As I suppose, you can have some table `tbl_product_filters` with M:1 relation to your `tbl_products` that contains filter names and values for each product id.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_product_filters`
(
  `id` int(10) unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `product_id` ...,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255)
)..;
```

You can also normalize it further and isolate filter names as filter types in separate table to substitute string `name` to integer `type_id`. It would be faster I suppose.